# Eclipse m2e plugin issue for cyclic dependent projects

Tags: eclipse, m2eclipse

I have an issue with m2e plugin for cyclic dependent projects.

First of all, I know that circular dependencies are bad , maven also does not permit it, they should be avoided and etc. but our legacy projects were mavenized without project structure change (circular dependencies were continued).

Previously, adding each project to other projects build path and setting circular dependencies build path problem to warning was the workaround solution. That way, I could make changes in one project and see the effect in the other immediately.

Now that projects are mavenized, I want to achieve the same workspace environment by enabling m2e workspace resolution (by checking "Resolve dependencies from workspace projects" option).

In eclipse neon (Version: Neon.3 Release (4.6.3) Build id: 20170314-1500) with m2e version 1.7.0.20160603-1933 this is possible. Corresponding maven dependency is resolved from workspace project although there is cycle in build path.

However, in eclipse 2019-09 R  (Version: 2019-09 R (4.13.0) Build id: 20190917-1200 with m2e version 1.13.0.20190716-1624) and later releases,  build results in infinite loop.
For two cyclic projects MY PROJECT A  and MY PROJECT B with maven artifact ids MYPROJECTAARTIFACTID, MYPROJECTBARTIFACTID respectively, below is the m2e log for infinite build from 2019-09 R version (I could not gather logs from neon version).

To repeat, I know that maven itself does not allow cyclic project setup but in general eclipse does allow it even for projects with maven nature.

How can I achieve the same in latest eclipse releases?

```
2020-05-22 21:19:26,588 [Worker-7: Building Workspace] DEBUG o.e.m.c.i.builder.MavenBuilder - Building project MY PROJECT B
2020-05-22 21:19:26,683 [Worker-7: Building Workspace] DEBUG o.e.a.i.i.DefaultLocalRepositoryProvider - Using manager EnhancedLocalRepositoryManager with priority 10.0 for D:\MAVEN_REPONEW
2020-05-22 21:19:26,697 [Worker-7: Building Workspace] DEBUG o.e.m.c.i.p.r.ProjectRegistryManager - Refreshing: [L/MY PROJECT B/pom.xml]
2020-05-22 21:19:26,709 [Worker-7: Building Workspace] DEBUG o.e.a.i.i.DefaultLocalRepositoryProvider - Using manager EnhancedLocalRepositoryManager with priority 10.0 for D:\MAVEN_REPONEW
2020-05-22 21:19:26,712 [Worker-7: Building Workspace] DEBUG o.e.m.c.internal.embedder.MavenImpl - Reading 1 Maven project(s): [D:\LOCALGITREPOS\CYCLE_2019\MYPROJECTBARTIFACTID\MY PROJECT B\pom.xml]
2020-05-22 21:19:26,764 [Worker-7: Building Workspace] DEBUG o.e.a.i.i.DefaultUpdatePolicyAnalyzer - Skipped remote request for ...
2020-05-22 21:19:26,868 [Worker-7: Building Workspace] DEBUG o.e.m.c.internal.embedder.MavenImpl - Read 1 Maven project(s) in 156 ms
2020-05-22 21:19:27,036 [Worker-7: Building Workspace] DEBUG o.e.m.c.i.m.MavenMarkerManager - Created marker 'GroupId is duplicate of parent groupId' on resource '/MY PROJECT B/pom.xml'.
2020-05-22 21:19:27,043 [Worker-7: Building Workspace] DEBUG o.e.a.i.i.DefaultLocalRepositoryProvider - Using manager EnhancedLocalRepositoryManager with priority 10.0 for D:\MAVEN_REPONEW
2020-05-22 21:19:27,086 [Worker-7: Building Workspace] DEBUG o.e.m.c.i.l.LifecycleMappingFactory - Loading lifecycle mapping for MavenProject: com.my.company:MYPROJECTBARTIFACTID:1.0.1-SNAPSHOT @ D:\LOCALGITREPOS\CYCLE_2019\MYPROJECTBARTIFACTID\MY PROJECT B\pom.xml.
2020-05-22 21:19:27,670 [Worker-7: Building Workspace] DEBUG o.e.a.i.i.c.DefaultDependencyCollector - Dependency collection stats: {ConflictMarker.analyzeTime=637200, ConflictMarker.markTime=709300, ConflictMarker.nodeCount=118, ConflictIdSorter.graphTime=487300, ConflictIdSorter.topsortTime=290200, ConflictIdSorter.conflictIdCount=45, ConflictIdSorter.conflictIdCycleCount=0, ConflictResolver.totalTime=3881500, ConflictResolver.conflictItemCount=72, DefaultDependencyCollector.collectTime=398895400, DefaultDependencyCollector.transformTime=7801200}
2020-05-22 21:19:27,785 [Worker-7: Building Workspace] INFO  o.e.m.c.i.l.LifecycleMappingFactory - Using org.eclipse.m2e.jdt.JarLifecycleMapping lifecycle mapping for MavenProject: com.my.company:MYPROJECTBARTIFACTID:1.0.1-SNAPSHOT @ D:\LOCALGITREPOS\CYCLE_2019\MYPROJECTBARTIFACTID\MY PROJECT B\pom.xml.
2020-05-22 21:19:27,785 [Worker-7: Building Workspace] DEBUG o.e.m.c.i.l.LifecycleMappingFactory - Loaded lifecycle mapping in 699 ms for MavenProject: com.my.company:MYPROJECTBARTIFACTID:1.0.1-SNAPSHOT @ D:\LOCALGITREPOS\CYCLE_2019\MYPROJECTBARTIFACTID\MY PROJECT B\pom.xml.
2020-05-22 21:19:27,785 [Worker-7: Building Workspace] DEBUG o.e.m.c.i.l.LifecycleMappingFactory - MY PROJECT B is configured by :
2020-05-22 21:19:27,785 [Worker-7: Building Workspace] DEBUG o.e.m.c.i.l.LifecycleMappingFactory -  - org.eclipse.m2e.jdt.javaConfigurator
2020-05-22 21:19:27,785 [Worker-7: Building Workspace] DEBUG o.e.m.c.i.l.LifecycleMappingFactory -  - org.maven.ide.eclipse.configuration.wtp.java.unsupportedDependencyTypeConfigurator
2020-05-22 21:19:27,785 [Worker-7: Building Workspace] DEBUG o.e.m.c.i.l.LifecycleMappingFactory -  - org.eclipse.m2e.wtp.jpa.configurator.jdt
2020-05-22 21:19:27,785 [Worker-7: Building Workspace] DEBUG o.e.m.c.i.l.LifecycleMappingFactory -  - org.maven.ide.eclipse.configuration.wtp.utility.configurator
2020-05-22 21:19:27,785 [Worker-7: Building Workspace] DEBUG o.e.m.c.i.l.LifecycleMappingFactory -  - org.maven.ide.eclipse.configuration.wtp.webfragment.configurator
2020-05-22 21:19:27,785 [Worker-7: Building Workspace] DEBUG o.e.m.c.i.l.LifecycleMappingFactory -  - org.sonatype.m2e.mavenarchiver.jararchiverconfigurator
2020-05-22 21:19:27,785 [Worker-7: Building Workspace] DEBUG o.e.m.c.i.l.LifecycleMappingFactory -  - org.eclipse.m2e.wtp.jaxrs.configurator
2020-05-22 21:19:27,786 [Worker-7: Building Workspace] DEBUG o.e.m.c.i.p.r.DefaultMavenDependencyResolver - Resolving dependencies for P/MY PROJECT B: com.my.company:MYPROJECTBARTIFACTID:1.0.1-SNAPSHOT
2020-05-22 21:19:27,786 [Worker-7: Building Workspace] DEBUG o.e.m.c.internal.embedder.MavenImpl - Reading Maven project: D:\LOCALGITREPOS\CYCLE_2019\MYPROJECTBARTIFACTID\MY PROJECT B\pom.xml
2020-05-22 21:19:27,790 [Worker-7: Building Workspace] DEBUG o.e.a.i.i.DefaultUpdatePolicyAnalyzer - Skipped remote request for com.my.company:... locally cached metadata up-to-date.
2020-05-22 21:19:28,529 [Worker-7: Building Workspace] DEBUG o.e.a.i.i.c.DefaultDependencyCollector - Dependency collection stats: {ConflictMarker.analyzeTime=925200, ConflictMarker.markTime=269600, ConflictMarker.nodeCount=328, ConflictIdSorter.graphTime=1694200, ConflictIdSorter.topsortTime=470600, ConflictIdSorter.conflictIdCount=88, ConflictIdSorter.conflictIdCycleCount=48, ConflictResolver.totalTime=7407900, ConflictResolver.conflictItemCount=309, DefaultDependencyCollector.collectTime=730670400, DefaultDependencyCollector.transformTime=10784800}
2020-05-22 21:19:28,539 [Worker-7: Building Workspace] INFO  o.e.m.c.i.p.WorkspaceClassifierResolverManager - Resolving P/MY PROJECT A: com.my.company:MYPROJECTAARTIFACTID:1.0.1-SNAPSHOT with classifier  to /MY PROJECT A/target/classes
2020-05-22 21:19:28,598 [Worker-7: Building Workspace] DEBUG o.e.m.c.internal.embedder.MavenImpl - Read Maven project: D:\LOCALGITREPOS\CYCLE_2019\MYPROJECTBARTIFACTID\MY PROJECT B\pom.xml in 812 ms
2020-05-22 21:19:28,598 [Worker-7: Building Workspace] DEBUG o.e.m.c.i.p.r.DefaultMavenDependencyResolver - Resolved dependencies for P/MY PROJECT B: com.my.company:MYPROJECTBARTIFACTID:1.0.1-SNAPSHOT in 812 ms
2020-05-22 21:19:28,600 [Worker-7: Building Workspace] DEBUG o.e.a.i.i.DefaultLocalRepositoryProvider - Using manager EnhancedLocalRepositoryManager with priority 10.0 for D:\MAVEN_REPONEW
2020-05-22 21:19:28,601 [Worker-7: Building Workspace] DEBUG o.e.m.c.i.l.LifecycleMappingFactory - Loading lifecycle mapping for MavenProject: com.my.company:MYPROJECTBARTIFACTID:1.0.1-SNAPSHOT @ D:\LOCALGITREPOS\CYCLE_2019\MYPROJECTBARTIFACTID\MY PROJECT B\pom.xml.
2020-05-22 21:19:28,607 [Worker-1: Decoration Calculation] DEBUG o.e.j.i.storage.file.FileSnapshot - file=C:\Program Files\Git\etc\gitconfig, isRacyClean=false, read=2020-05-22 21:18:57.612000000, lastModified=2020-04-28 20:51:11.602527000, delta=2075266009473000 ns, racy<=2500000000 ns
2020-05-22 21:19:28,607 [Worker-1: Decoration Calculation] DEBUG o.e.j.i.storage.file.FileSnapshot - file=C:\Program Files\Git\etc\gitconfig, is unmodified
.......
2020-05-22 21:19:28,677 [Worker-7: Building Workspace] INFO  o.e.m.c.i.l.LifecycleMappingFactory - Using org.eclipse.m2e.jdt.JarLifecycleMapping lifecycle mapping for MavenProject: com.my.company:MYPROJECTBARTIFACTID:1.0.1-SNAPSHOT @ D:\LOCALGITREPOS\CYCLE_2019\MYPROJECTBARTIFACTID\MY PROJECT B\pom.xml.
2020-05-22 21:19:28,678 [Worker-7: Building Workspace] DEBUG o.e.m.c.i.l.LifecycleMappingFactory - Loaded lifecycle mapping in 77 ms for MavenProject: com.my.company:MYPROJECTBARTIFACTID:1.0.1-SNAPSHOT @ D:\LOCALGITREPOS\CYCLE_2019\MYPROJECTBARTIFACTID\MY PROJECT B\pom.xml.
2020-05-22 21:19:28,678 [Worker-7: Building Workspace] DEBUG o.e.m.c.i.l.LifecycleMappingFactory - MY PROJECT B is configured by :
2020-05-22 21:19:28,678 [Worker-7: Building Workspace] DEBUG o.e.m.c.i.l.LifecycleMappingFactory -  - org.eclipse.m2e.jdt.javaConfigurator
2020-05-22 21:19:28,678 [Worker-7: Building Workspace] DEBUG o.e.m.c.i.l.LifecycleMappingFactory -  - org.maven.ide.eclipse.configuration.wtp.java.unsupportedDependencyTypeConfigurator
2020-05-22 21:19:28,678 [Worker-7: Building Workspace] DEBUG o.e.m.c.i.l.LifecycleMappingFactory -  - org.eclipse.m2e.wtp.jpa.configurator.jdt
2020-05-22 21:19:28,678 [Worker-7: Building Workspace] DEBUG o.e.m.c.i.l.LifecycleMappingFactory -  - org.maven.ide.eclipse.configuration.wtp.utility.configurator
2020-05-22 21:19:28,678 [Worker-7: Building Workspace] DEBUG o.e.m.c.i.l.LifecycleMappingFactory -  - org.maven.ide.eclipse.configuration.wtp.webfragment.configurator
2020-05-22 21:19:28,678 [Worker-7: Building Workspace] DEBUG o.e.m.c.i.l.LifecycleMappingFactory -  - org.sonatype.m2e.mavenarchiver.jararchiverconfigurator
2020-05-22 21:19:28,678 [Worker-7: Building Workspace] DEBUG o.e.m.c.i.l.LifecycleMappingFactory -  - org.eclipse.m2e.wtp.jaxrs.configurator
2020-05-22 21:19:28,678 [Worker-7: Building Workspace] DEBUG o.e.m.c.i.p.r.DefaultMavenDependencyResolver - Resolving dependencies for P/MY PROJECT B: com.my.company:MYPROJECTBARTIFACTID:1.0.1-SNAPSHOT
2020-05-22 21:19:28,678 [Worker-7: Building Workspace] DEBUG o.e.m.c.internal.embedder.MavenImpl - Reading Maven project: D:\LOCALGITREPOS\CYCLE_2019\MYPROJECTBARTIFACTID\MY PROJECT B\pom.xml
2020-05-22 21:19:28,689 [Worker-7: Building Workspace] DEBUG o.e.a.i.i.c.DefaultDependencyCollector - Dependency collection stats: {ConflictMarker.analyzeTime=288800, ConflictMarker.markTime=102300, ConflictMarker.nodeCount=328, ConflictIdSorter.graphTime=336300, ConflictIdSorter.topsortTime=260900, ConflictIdSorter.conflictIdCount=88, ConflictIdSorter.conflictIdCycleCount=48, ConflictResolver.totalTime=3849800, ConflictResolver.conflictItemCount=309, DefaultDependencyCollector.collectTime=5078800, DefaultDependencyCollector.transformTime=4849700}
2020-05-22 21:19:28,697 [Worker-7: Building Workspace] INFO  o.e.m.c.i.p.WorkspaceClassifierResolverManager - Resolving P/MY PROJECT A: com.my.company:MYPROJECTAARTIFACTID:1.0.1-SNAPSHOT with classifier  to /MY PROJECT A/target/classes
2020-05-22 21:19:28,739 [Worker-7: Building Workspace] DEBUG o.e.m.c.internal.embedder.MavenImpl - Read Maven project: D:\LOCALGITREPOS\CYCLE_2019\MYPROJECTBARTIFACTID\MY PROJECT B\pom.xml in 61 ms
2020-05-22 21:19:28,739 [Worker-7: Building Workspace] DEBUG o.e.m.c.i.p.r.DefaultMavenDependencyResolver - Resolved dependencies for P/MY PROJECT B: com.my.company:MYPROJECTBARTIFACTID:1.0.1-SNAPSHOT in 61 ms
2020-05-22 21:19:28,740 [Worker-7: Building Workspace] DEBUG o.e.a.i.i.DefaultLocalRepositoryProvider - Using manager EnhancedLocalRepositoryManager with priority 10.0 for D:\MAVEN_REPONEW
2020-05-22 21:19:28,741 [Worker-7: Building Workspace] DEBUG o.e.m.c.i.l.LifecycleMappingFactory - Loading lifecycle mapping for MavenProject: com.my.company:MYPROJECTBARTIFACTID:1.0.1-SNAPSHOT @ D:\LOCALGITREPOS\CYCLE_2019\MYPROJECTBARTIFACTID\MY PROJECT B\pom.xml.
2020-05-22 21:19:28,804 [Worker-7: Building Workspace] INFO  o.e.m.c.i.l.LifecycleMappingFactory - Using org.eclipse.m2e.jdt.JarLifecycleMapping lifecycle mapping for MavenProject: com.my.company:MYPROJECTBARTIFACTID:1.0.1-SNAPSHOT @ D:\LOCALGITREPOS\CYCLE_2019\MYPROJECTBARTIFACTID\MY PROJECT B\pom.xml.
2020-05-22 21:19:28,804 [Worker-7: Building Workspace] DEBUG o.e.m.c.i.l.LifecycleMappingFactory - Loaded lifecycle mapping in 63 ms for MavenProject: com.my.company:MYPROJECTBARTIFACTID:1.0.1-SNAPSHOT @ D:\LOCALGITREPOS\CYCLE_2019\MYPROJECTBARTIFACTID\MY PROJECT B\pom.xml.
2020-05-22 21:19:28,804 [Worker-7: Building Workspace] DEBUG o.e.m.c.i.l.LifecycleMappingFactory - MY PROJECT B is configured by :
2020-05-22 21:19:28,804 [Worker-7: Building Workspace] DEBUG o.e.m.c.i.l.LifecycleMappingFactory -  - org.eclipse.m2e.jdt.javaConfigurator
2020-05-22 21:19:28,804 [Worker-7: Building Workspace] DEBUG o.e.m.c.i.l.LifecycleMappingFactory -  - org.maven.ide.eclipse.configuration.wtp.java.unsupportedDependencyTypeConfigurator
2020-05-22 21:19:28,804 [Worker-7: Building Workspace] DEBUG o.e.m.c.i.l.LifecycleMappingFactory -  - org.eclipse.m2e.wtp.jpa.configurator.jdt
2020-05-22 21:19:28,804 [Worker-7: Building Workspace] DEBUG o.e.m.c.i.l.LifecycleMappingFactory -  - org.maven.ide.eclipse.configuration.wtp.utility.configurator
2020-05-22 21:19:28,804 [Worker-7: Building Workspace] DEBUG o.e.m.c.i.l.LifecycleMappingFactory -  - org.maven.ide.eclipse.configuration.wtp.webfragment.configurator
2020-05-22 21:19:28,804 [Worker-7: Building Workspace] DEBUG o.e.m.c.i.l.LifecycleMappingFactory -  - org.sonatype.m2e.mavenarchiver.jararchiverconfigurator
2020-05-22 21:19:28,804 [Worker-7: Building Workspace] DEBUG o.e.m.c.i.l.LifecycleMappingFactory -  - org.eclipse.m2e.wtp.jaxrs.configurator
2020-05-22 21:19:28,804 [Worker-7: Building Workspace] DEBUG o.e.m.c.i.p.r.DefaultMavenDependencyResolver - Resolving dependencies for P/MY PROJECT B: com.my.company:MYPROJECTBARTIFACTID:1.0.1-SNAPSHOT
................
```

**-----------------------------EDIT 1--------------------------**

Sample project added to github ( https://github.com/simpleusr/eclipseproblem ) for reproducing the issue. It also fails with latest eclipse Version: 2020-03 (4.15.0) Build id: 20200313-1211

Comment: _"How can I achieve the same in latest eclipse releases?"_ ← At least you have to install the latest Eclipse release for that. Using outdated software is bad, too. Please show a minimal example to reproduced your issue in the current Eclipse version (since two projects and multiple files are involved, put it into a public Git repository and link to it).

Comment: @howlger Thanks for the response. Per your request, I added a minimal reproducer project at  https://github.com/simpleusr/eclipseproblem . Please note that it also fails with latest version  2020-03 (4.15.0) Build id: 20200313-1211. I attached m2e logs for both versions. Thanks...

Comment: Eclipse allows the compilation of multiple projects with cyclic dependencies. But here, resolving (Maven) dependencies leads to the infinite loop, which is a different thing. Since Maven does not allow cyclic dependencies, you can't build this from command line either, right? In Eclipse it works without the invalid dependencies and configuring the _Java Build Path_ manually. Is it a requirement to build the projects with Maven (on the command line), or do you want to (mis)use Maven to manage the dependencies only?

Comment: @howlger Thanks for the response. Let me give some brief history of what resulted this ugly situation. In our code base, there are over 20 highly coupled projects with circular dependencies all of which are infrastructure components of a fairly old (above 20 years) monolith system. Previously, project builds were performed locally on developer computers via eclipse jar export after code commit. A modernization project began and the most important concern was to perform server side builds via a standard build tool , which happened to be maven...

Comment: But during mavenization stage, no structural changes to remove cycles (which would mean change of package names of public classes used by numerous components) were done on projects. Instead, in order to minimize effort, jars of exising projects were manually uploaded to artifact repository and this enabled building of each mavenized project separately, i.e. that way it is possible to "cheat" maven for cyclic dependencies. If the projects were bundled as a multimodule project, maven reactor would not build them as you say...

Comment: As I said, since projects are  highly coupled and numerous in size, even a simple development or a bug fix requires change in multiple projects and as you may guess, this is very cumbersome without enabling workspace resolution. Current trick is to change a component and install it to local repo to see the change in other components and repeating this process for all changes. But even this is not feasible because there is no real versioning , a single snapshot version is used for all artifacts and unfortunately, this results in collisions between locally installed and remote repo artifacts...

Comment: I totally agree with all of your comments, this is a misuse of maven but my point is : Although it contradicts with nature of maven, eclipse neon somehow(?) handles this and allows us to enable workspace resolution. This speeds up development time considerably (as opposed to mvn install after each component change procedure). I was wondering if there is a way to keep this behavior in latest release (since we want to use the latest release of eclipse instead of being stuck in neon) . Best regards

Comment: I only see two options: (a) eliminate the cycles or (b) put everything into a single Maven project (maybe with multiple source folders). If you choose option (b), you can split the built JAR into several JARs in a post-processing step. This has the same disadvantage as with multiple cyclically interdependent projects: stuff may be missing at runtime if not the entire code with all dependencies is on the classpath. Based on my experience, I would recommend option (a), since the time invested (probably weeks) pays off in the long run (and it's more fun to have modularized than spaghetti code).

Comment: @howlger thanks again for your valuable suggestions. So as far as I understand there is no way of keeping old (probably faulty) behavior in later releases? I am still wondering how neon was able to handle that... By the way you may post your comments as answer for me to accept if you want. Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse allows the **compilation of multiple projects with circular dependencies**. But here, **resolving the Maven dependencies leads to the infinite loop**, which is a different thing. To resolve and download the dependencies, Eclipse uses the embedded Maven, that is shipped with the Eclipse IDE.

Since **Maven does not allow cyclic dependencies**, you can't build this from command line either. In Eclipse, it would work without the invalid Maven dependencies to the other project in the `pom.xml` files, by adding the other project in the Java Build Path manually and allowing circular dependencies for the Java Compiler. But these manually settings will be overwritten on *Maven > Update Project...*.

If you want to use Maven to build your projects, you have two options:

- Put everything into a **single Maven project**, maybe with multiple source folders. You can split the built JAR into several JARs in a post-processing step. This has the same disadvantage as with multiple circular interdependent projects: stuff may be missing at runtime if not the entire code with all dependencies is on the classpath.
- **Eliminate the cycles**. Based on my experience, this is what I would recommend, since the time invested (probably weeks) pays off in the long run (and it's more fun to have modularized code than spaghetti code).